# In Google Docs, how to create a form that can store the data entered into it in an excel sheet automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-docs, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

The title pretty much says it all.

I need to create a poll wherein I need to ask the users some questions.
How can I do it using **Google Docs**? How will I **access the data entered** after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the form using *New > Form* menu. When you create a form in Google Docs, it automatically stores the responses in a spreadsheet. In the spreadsheet, you'll find related items in the *Form* menu item. Refer to the Google Help instructions for [working with forms](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=15166).

Comment: thanks. so silly i din't find it myself. Actually I was trying to make a form inside a spreadsheet :)